# Use 2 key to make relations on Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

This example structure of the old project.

```
public class Customs
{

    [Key,Required, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string DeclarationNo { get; set; }

    [Key, Required, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ReceivedControlNo { get; set; }

    [Key, Required, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string MasterBL { get; set; }

    public string CustomsDetail {get;set;}

    public virtual CustomsManifest Manifest { get; set; }
 }


public class CustomsManifest
{
    [Key,Required, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ReceivedControlNo { get; set; }
    [Key,Required, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string MasterBL { get; set; }
    public string ManifestDetail {get; set; }

    public virtual Customs Customs { get; set; }
}
```

How to make relations with 2 key. is it possible?

the Key I need to join between Customs & CustomsManifest is

1. ReceivedControlNo
2. MasterBL

Relationship's **zero or one**

Comment: Can you check the posted model class names - what is `Manifest` and `CustomsPermit`?

Comment: @IvanStoev thank that's my typo.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately EF does not support explicit FK for such relationship. You have to sacrifice `CustomsManifest.Customs` navigation property and configure using `WithMany` as described [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations)

Comment: How would you go with that? `Customs` may have unique records with identical `ReceivedControlNo` and `MasterBL` values, but there can only be *one* `CustomsManifest` having these values. That's all kinds of ambiguities and errors waiting to happen.